# Click event on table in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have html, I need to append a row in a table dynamically, also I need to catch the click event in the append div class. How to achieve this any idea?

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#click").click(function() {
        $('table').prepend('<tr> <td>something3</td> <td> <a><div class="s"> s </a> </td></tr>');
    });


    $(".s").click(function() {
        alert("Ok");
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="click" value="click"/>

<table width='100%'>
    <tr><td>something</td><td>else here</td></tr>
    <tr><td>something2</td><td>else here2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>something3</td><td>else here3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The HTML code you append is a mess. You need to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) method, it allows you to bind an event for all current, and future elements in the DOM that match the given selector.

```
 $(".s").live('click', function(){
    alert("Ok");

 });
```

[jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/live) say:

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future

---

**Note** that this answer was written in October 2011, when jQuery 1.6.4 was king. `live()` was deprecated in 1.7 in favour of using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on). The equivalent syntax is now;

```
 $(document).on("click", ".s", function(){
    alert("Ok");
 });
```

Comment: Most jQuery experts recommend the .delegate function rather than the .live function: http://test.kingdesk.com/jquery/bind_live_delegate.php

Comment: Correct, I would add however that delegate is considered to be faster and more flexible (chain-able) to live. http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: update to my previous comment, on() was introduced since this answer was posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359085/delegate-vs-on